# render partial of another namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem. I need to render objects using partials of another namespace.

```
 render complain.target
```

it tryes to render partial from current namespace(current is `admin`)

> Missing partial admin/bulletins/bulletin...

I dont need to render it from admin/..

I cant specify partial path like

```
render partial: '/bulletins/bulletin', locals: { bulletin: complain.target }
```

But it's polymorphic association, and different partial pathes are used. 
Is it any way to do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be no possible way to achieve this with a `render complain.target` call (Checked on Rails 5 source).

There is a config option for action_view to disable namespace prepending for partials, though:

```
     Rails.application.config.action_view.prefix_partial_path_with_controller_namespace = false
```

**EDIT**

Today, I've used another solution:
When rendering Single-Table-Inheritance models into partials, one can pass the locals variable name based on the Rails model_name lookup, when calling the render partial:

```
<%= render partial: "admin/#{object.to_partial_path}", 
           locals: { object.model_name.element => object } 
%>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, you can see the pull request: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/5625

Answer (score 1):

You can use `render "/#{complain.target.to_partial_path}"`