# Rails 5.0.0.1 namspaced controller and render partial. bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces

I'm having an issue with render partial: from within a namespaced controller. I should be able to render any partial from the views relative to the views folder, however, I'm unable to do so. It appends the partial path with the namespace, regardless of whatever I do. This controller responds to ajax calls and returns html.

Expected

```
1) render partial: "foos/bar" => "app/views/foos/_bar.html.haml"
2) render partial: "/foos/bar" => "app/views/foos/_bar.html.haml"
```

Getting

```
1) render partial: "foos/bar" => "app/views/ajax_api/foos/_bar.html.haml"
2) render partial: "/foos/bar" => "app/views/ajax_api//foos/_bar.html.haml"
note on 2 extra "/"
```

It does not matter what I have tried the result is

```
ActionView::Template::Error:
       Missing partial 'insert above output'
```

Routes

```
 namespace :ajax_api do
    resource :setup, only: [] do
      post :selection, on: :member
      post :deployment, on: :member
    end
  end
```

Comment: Could you show what you tried to describe the full path and what error you got?

Comment: @Joel_Blum I have edited my question to better reflect your comment, the full path I did try was "app/views/foos/bar", same result.

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that namespaces take priority over a defined route, always

However seems an option was added to turn off prefixing of namespace.
see: [render partial of another namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376012/render-partial-of-another-namespace)

I think I'm going to refactor my routes, to not use a namespace.

**Discussion**

A leading slash in the defined route should always take precedence over a namespace?